# Как сделать, чтобы в richTextBox сохранялось форматирование текста?

Tags: c#, winforms

Форматирую сообщение в richTextBox следующим кодом:

```
// СООБЩЕНИЕ      
richTextBox1.Text += (" СООБЩЕНИЕ " + "\r\n");  

// ПОДСВЕТКА                                  
richTextBox1.Select(richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(" СООБЩЕНИЕ "), " СООБЩЕНИЕ ".Length);
richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.LimeGreen;

// ПРОКРУТКА
richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
```

после появления следующей строчки с текстом в richTextBox форматирование предыдущей строки исчезает.

**Вопрос**
1. Как сделать чтобы при добавлении новых строк в richTextBox форматирование предыдущих строк сохранялось?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод Append добавляет текст уже к имеющемся.

Правильно:

```
richTextBox1.AppendText(" СООБЩЕНИЕ " + "\r\n");
```

[Взято отсюда, 1я ссылка гугла.](http://www.cyberforum.ru/windows-forms/thread516549.html)

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как быть со следующей проблемой.. Форматирование происходит только при первом проходе цикла, а пир последующих текст не форматируется. Код - https://codeshare.io/5wydoB; Скрин - http://prntscr.com/f3i2ge